# Angular 7 - Prevent other fields data removing on submit

Tags: angular

I have a form which contains multiple TEXTAREA elements displaying through loop. Every TEXTAREA has it's own submit button and the value is submitting correctly.
But if I enter some text in textarea-1 and don't submit it, then I write some text in textarea-2 and click the submit button, it'll submit the relevant content but also refreshes/removes the text in the textarea-1. I want the text in textarea-1 to remain there untill its submitted button clicks.
I googled this, but couldn't find exactly what I was searching.

Here is the code:

```
 <form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
  <div class="single-field" *ngFor="let project of projectsArr; let i = index;" #ival>
     <mat-form-field>
          <textarea matInput class="md-textarea form-control dc-text-field__input mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label" rows="3" cols="40" name="info{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="projectsArr[i].info"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
 </div>
 <mat-card-actions>
   <button class="mat-button" name="submitButton" #submitButton id="button{{i}}" type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!projectsArr[i].info" (click)="saveInfo(info, i)">
    <span class="mat-button__label">Save Now</span>
   </button>
</mat-card-actions>
</form>
```

// SAVE UPDATE METHOD

```
saveUpdate(proj, index) {
if(this.isLoading){
  return;
}
this.isLoading  = true;

if (proj.hasOwnProperty('progress')) {
  this.fs.removeMyTodaysUpdate(this.today.toDateString(), proj.name,  this.currentUser.email).then(() => {
    this.storeUpdate(proj, index);
  }).catch(err=>{
    this.isLoading = false;
  })
} else {
  this.storeUpdate(proj, index);     
}
```

}

Comment: add your `saveInfo` method content here

Comment: You should probably add a [`trackBy`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description) function to your ngFor. The change detection of the submit, and the retrieving of items is probably causing your elements to render again

Comment: pass event into the function called on submitand then `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating only `one submit button in each form and change button type to submit`.

Please find the ref code.

```
<form *ngFor="let project of projectsArr; let i = index;">
        <mat-form-field>
           <textarea matInput class="md-textarea form-control dc-text-field__input mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label" rows="3" cols="40" name="info{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="projectsArr[i].info"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>

         <mat-card-actions>
           <button class="mat-button" name="submitButton" #submitButton id="button{{i}}" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!projectsArr[i].info" (click)="saveInfo(info, i)">
            <span class="mat-button__label">Save Now</span>
           </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
</form>
```

Comment: change the button type to submit